# No se actualiza URL en browser

Tags: java

quisiera conocer la posible causa del siguiente problema: al acceder a una URL y luego  ingreso en una de las opciones, el navegador no refleja la posicion actual dentro del sitio (no actualiza la URL)...quisiera saber si alguien sabe algo al respecto...el proyecto esta construido en JAVA (MVC)

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Julio. Noy hay suficientes detalles concretos en la pregunta para poder ayudarte. Con la información disponible, solo se puede adivinar.

Comment: Si estás haciendo forward y no redirect, el cambio de url no será visible en la barra de navegación. Indica más acerca de tu aplicación, framework empleado (si usas uno), y te diremos cómo solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

En Java, cuando no sucede la "actualización de la URL" es debido a que se hace un FORWARD y no un redirect. Comentas que estás usando MVC, el controlador se encarga de procesar este FORWARD como respuesta hacia la vista para que esta la muestre.